# In angular 2 app how can I cache certain local resources e.g. scripts

Tags: .htaccess, angular

In angular 2 app how can I cache certain local resources e.g. scripts

Can I use a .htaccess file at my route?

I have an app thats live and when I run a speed page test with [gtmetrix.com](http://gtmetrix.com)
I get an issue with [leverage browser caching](https://gtmetrix.com/leverage-browser-caching.html) and it says to cache some of my resources as I'm making too many requests even though these resources are stored locally with the app.

I'm not sure if an angular2 app can have a .htaccess file? or what it would look like for a file.

If I cannot use a .htaccess file can you let me know other ways please.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

.htaccess is configuration for the server, so if you host your app on apache-server you can use a .htaccess -file

Angular can not help you cache files such as images

If the requests are for multiple js-files that are angular components of your app you should look at bundling your scripts into fewer files.

If you are a beginner i recommend you build your app using angular-cli that can help you with a build workflow.